# TinyMCE causes page to jump

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

So I have the following call to a tinyMCE editor when a user presses the edit button.

```
   function edit () {

     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false, selectedEditBox.attr('id') );
     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus',false, selectedEditBox.attr('id') );

  }
```

The following is the init code for tinyMCE

```
   tinyMCE.init({

editor_selector : "mceSimple",
mode : "none",
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "closeButton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink,pastetext,selectall",
plugins : "autoresize, paste",
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
    console.log(o.content);
},
paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
    console.log(o.node.innerHTML);
},
theme_advanced_resizing : true,                
setup : function(ed) {
    // Add a custom button
    ed.addButton('closeButton', {
        title : 'Close',
        image : '/images/editComplete.png',
        onclick : function() {
            hideEditor ( ed);
        }
      });
   }


 });
```

So this works fine and it adds the  box to the selected element. The problem is that when I do this the page jumps. The first section I change causes the page to jump to the bottom of the page however every other editor I create causes the box to jump to the top of the page. Does anyone know what causes it or how to fix it?

Any answers much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your mceFocus call is backwards - per the docs, mceFocus should be the first argument.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, forgot to change the code back, I have tried it both ways with the same problem. Updated the code.

Comment: What type of button is it? button element? anchor element? input element? div? What is the cause of the jump? the increased/decreased height of the page, or is the scroll position actually changing.

Comment: The page has a number of divs(which can change). Hovering over each div causes a button to appear which when pressed creates the editor. The editor tehn replaces the div. The page itself doesn't change size. The scrollbar is set to either the end or the bottom depending on if its the first editor that has been created or not.

Comment: hmm, you could use the tinymce setup config parameter plus an onInit handler and set the focus there: ed.focus()

Comment: Nope, that doesnt make a difference either.

Comment: @Chaney, did you find a fix? I have the same problem.